# Wrapping optional types to Dict to use in Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm using AlamoFire to make a post call that is failing because the json is missing a field. The problem seems to be because of an optional variable I'm trying to put in the json to send to backend.

```
func toJSON() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

    let subCategory = self.adCategory!.toJSON()

    let images = self.adImages
    var imgArray = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
    for image in images! {
        let img = image as! AdImage
        imgArray.append(img.toJSON())
    }

    return [
        "title": self.title as AnyObject,
        "description": self.adDescription as AnyObject,
        "category": subCategory as AnyObject,
        "images": imgArray as AnyObject
    ]
}
```

Title, Description and images work fine. Category don't.

When I print the dictionary before calling Alamofire, category comes with '=' instead of ':'and also with ';', as you can see below:

```
"category": {
    parent =     {
         slug = "weird-widgets";
    };
slug = widgets;
```

This is the code toJSON() from the SubCategory:

```
func toJSON() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {

    let category = self.category?.toJSON()

    return [
        "slug": self.slug as AnyObject,
        "parent": category as AnyObject
    ]
}
```

Is there a correct way to wrap optional types to avoid this kind of issue? I tried several approaches but none of them is working.

Comment: try using optional binding.

Comment: Hi Tushar. I tried that approach, doing something like: if let category = self.category { ...}  but it also didn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks for you answer.